# How do I generate my request signature for AWS S3 uploads using the .NET API?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using the .NET API straight from Amazon to upload some files to S3.

However, I'm getting the exception message: `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

My code is as follows:

```
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client("myaccessid","mysecretid");
    List<string> allFileNames = ProcessFiles(@"c:\Dev\pktest\");
    foreach (string file in allFileNames)
    {                   

        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = "rhspktest",
            FilePath = file,
            Key = file,
            Timeout = 3600000                       
         };

         try
         {
             using (S3Response response = s3Client.PutObject(putObjectRequest)) { };
         }
         catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         }

            Console.WriteLine(file);

      }
      Console.Read();
```

Is there anything immediately obvious I'm doing wrong?

The ProcessFiles method just returns a list of filenames in that directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does `ProcessFiles` return just the filename or the complete path? Regardless, it's unlikely that `FilePath` and `Key` should be set to the same thing.

`FilePath` should be set to the full path of the local file to upload. eg `c:\Dev\pktest\myfile.txt`

`Key` is the name of the file to store on S3. eg `myfile.txt`. Or if you want keep the same path structure: `Dev/pktest/myfile.txt` (note the forward slashes)

Comment: Yes you're right. I think it was the backslashes that caused the issue.