# Amazon S3 & C# Signature does not match error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to Amazon AWS & trying to put (upload) the object (image in this case) to the bucket using the SDK for .NET using a console application shown below:

```
namespace AwsConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string bucketName = "bucketName";
        static string keyName = "keyName";
        static string filePath = "filePath";

        static IAmazonS3 client;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            NameValueCollection appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            string accessKeyID = appConfig["AWSAccessKey"];
            string secretAccessKeyID = appConfig["AWSSecretKey"];

            try
            {
                using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Uploading an object");
                    WritingAnObject();
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message, s3Exception.InnerException);
            }
            catch (AmazonSecurityTokenServiceException stsException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stsException.Message, stsException.InnerException);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Put object to AWS bucket
        /// </summary>
        static void WritingAnObject()
        {
            try
            {
                PutObjectRequest putRequest1 = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = keyName,
                    FilePath = filePath
                };

                PutObjectResponse response1 = client.PutObject(putRequest1);

            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
            {
                if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                    (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
                    ||
                    amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "For service sign up go to http://aws.amazon.com/s3");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Error occurred. Message:'{0}' when writing an object"
                        , amazonS3Exception.Message);
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I'm getting following error:

> *The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.Check your key  and signin method.*

Comment: You need to make sure your keys are exactly right - no extra spaces before or after them, and make sure no extra quotes.

Comment: Yes,I'm using those keys exactly right(I just cross-checked this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516030/how-do-i-generate-my-request-signature-for-aws-s3-uploads-using-the-net-api?rq=1).

I was defining `Key` as `"/folder/file.png"`,which is not correct as it has a forward-slash in the beginning of the `Key`.

The correct way of defining the `Key` is `"folder/file.png"`.

Answer (score 6):

Going to extend this answer by stating that since AWSSDK.Core version 3.7.107 the treatment of S3 bucket and file paths has a new breaking change.

Previously you were able to suffix the path onto the bucket name, and define the file name as just the filename part of the path.  After the above release, that no longer works and will give you the cryptic error message:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signin method.
```

You now need to move the file path as a prefix onto the file name.

More info is available here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/2622

```
 GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = "my-bucket/Folder", // No longer works
        Key = "fileName"
    };  

 GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = "my-bucket",
            Key = "Folder/fileName" // Works
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with error 403 and solved it by creating a new access key or credentials (Access Key Id,Secret Access Key) in my AWS IAM console.